# Entity scanning not working in JPA/hibernate/spring application

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, wildfly-10

My `applicationContext.xml`is:

```
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>

<context:component-scan base-package="com"/>
<context:annotation-config/>

<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>
<tx:jta-transaction-manager/>
<tx:annotation-driven/>

<jee:jndi-lookup id="corePU" jndi-name="java:/exampleDatasource" expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:/META-INF/persistence.xml" />
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="corePU" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com" />
</bean>
```

Each entity has `@Entity` and in `persistence.xml` following property is set

`<exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>`

```
Hibernate version : 5.1.0.Final
Spring version : 4.1.3.RELEASE
JPA 2.0
WildFly 10
```

In `applicationContext.xml` I have defined an entityManagerFactory bean as follows"

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:/META-INF/persistence.xml" />
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="corePU" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com" />
</bean>
```

`persistence.xml` is as follows:

```
<persistence-unit name="corePU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>java:/exampleDatasource</jta-data-source>
    <!--<class>com.entity.Address</class>-->

    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <!--<shared-cache-mode>NONE</shared-cache-mode>-->
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate" />

        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"/>
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false"/>
        <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.JBossStandAloneJtaPlatform"/>
        <property name="org.hibernate.envers.audit_table_prefix" value="z_"/>
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="false" />
        <property name="hibernate.generate_statistics" value="false"/>
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="false"/>
        <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class, hbm" />

    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Below is the error I am getting:

```
21:15:47,463 ERROR [stderr] (default task-4) java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown entity: com.entity.Address
21:15:47,463 ERROR [stderr] (default task-4)    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1149)
21:15:47,464 ERROR [stderr] (default task-4)    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
21:15:47,464 ERROR [stderr] (default task-4)    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
21:15:47,464 ERROR [stderr] (default task-4)    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
21:15:47,464 ERROR [stderr] (default task-4)    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
21:15:47,464 ERROR [stderr] (default task-4)    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:347)
21:15:47,464 ERROR [stderr] (default task-4)    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy93.persist(Unknown Source)
21:15:47,464 ERROR [stderr] (default task-4)    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
21:15:47,464 ERROR [stderr] (default task-4)    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
21:15:47,464 ERROR [stderr] (default task-4)    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
21:15:47,464 ERROR [stderr] (default task-4)    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
21:15:47,465 ERROR [stderr] (default task-4)    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:298)
21:15:47,465 ERROR [stderr] (default task-4)    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy50.persist(Unknown Source)
21:15:47,465 ERROR [stderr] (default task-4)    at com.manager.manager.getAddress(manager.java:37)
21:15:47,465 ERROR [stderr] (default task-4)    at com.manager.manager$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$e766fff.invoke(<generated>)
21:15:47,465 ERROR [stderr] (default task-4)    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
```

How can I use my entities without specifying each entity explicitly in `persistence.xml` with `class` tag?

Comment: `@ComponentScan` does not scan for Entities, since components are not entities. Outside of Spring Boot, there should be a parameter to give your EntityManagerFactory for that, afaik: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14368119/auto-scan-packages-for-jpa-entities-in-spring

Comment: you mean `<class>` tag in persistence unit is necessary? @FlorianSchaetz

Comment: No, as @Maciej Marczuk aready pointed out, there's a parameter for which packages to scan. No need to give each class explicitly. Otherwise you could use Spring Boot, which can automatically scan.

Comment: @FlorianSchaetz a bean is alredy defined in `applicationContext` I have edited the question can you check please? Thanks

Comment: If I were you, I would get rid of the persistence.xml, use only Spring to configure JPA there and then your property will work. Or even better, use Spring Boot, which makes it much simpler.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

JPA and Spring are two different things.

The Spring's `<context:component-scan base-package="..."/>` **has nothing to do with JPA**, in general. It refers to Spring components, bins, etc. But under the hood, of course, Spring uses JPA and there are two possible configurations of this:

- configure Spring to **read persistence.xml** and completely rely on it;
- **don't use persistence.xml** and use a Spring configuration only - another type of configuration, where you could use a `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` property `packagesToScan`. See this post, for example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16088340/2816631.

Check what Spring javadoc says about the `packagesToScan`:

> Set whether to use Spring-based scanning for entity classes in the
>   classpath instead of using JPA's standard scanning of jar files with
>   persistence.xml markers in them. In case of Spring-based scanning, no
>   persistence.xml is necessary; all you need to do is to specify base
>   packages to search here.

**If you want to use persistence.xml**, you have several options:

- write each entity class - JPA doesn't support auto-scan (well, almost, see the next option);
- don't write each entity class, but have your entities in one jar and set the `jar-file` property to point to it - JPA supports only this kind of auto-scan;
- if you don't mind being not JPA specification compliant (i.e. use a specific provider feature that JPA itself doesn't have), you can use **Hibernate auto-scan** feature:

**Hibernate auto-scan** feature:

```
<persistence-unit name="unitName" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
  <!-- This is required to be spec compliant, Hibernate however supports
       auto-detection even in JSE.
  <class>com.entity.User</class>
  <class>com.entity.Address</class>
  ...
   -->

  <properties>
    <!-- Scan for annotated classes and Hibernate mapping XML files -->
    <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class, hbm"/>
    ...
  </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Comment: Thanks :) What can I use to configure Spring to use `persistence.xml`?

Comment: I have added this property it is still not working, I am unable to understand what I am missing :(

Comment: I have edited my question to add `persistence.xml` can you have a look please?

Comment: @MDaniyal please, provide more of the applicationContext.xml that refers to jpa there, if anything.

Comment: this is the context file
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/c25677c6bceef68ff181532cbade928f

Comment: edited the question to include `applicationContext.xml` kindly have a look Thanks for the help :)

Comment: @MDaniyal thanks. What error do you get? How did you know it doesn't work?

Comment: This is the error I am getting, It is unable to find NamedQuery
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/222bb480bc61046f8c6c1cd6b4b1402b

Comment: This doesn't necessarily mean that entities are not found. It can be a completely different error. Can you, for example, save a new Address? If yes, entites are found and the error is in how you define queries.

Comment: when I define a class with `class` tag in perrsistenceUnit I can fetch records but on removing that class tag this error occurs

Comment: on saving entity I am getting this error: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown entity: com.entity.Address`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122043/discussion-between-artem-novikov-and-mdaniyal).

Answer (score 4):

You should set `packagesToScan` property in your `entityManager` / `sessionFactory` configuration.

for example:

`packagesToScan="com.manager"`

Alternatively, if you are using Spring Boot, you can use `@EntityScan` annotation:

[Spring Boot 1.4+](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/domain/EntityScan.html)

[Spring Boot < 1.4](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.3.5.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/boot/orm/jpa/EntityScan.html)

Comment: Thanks, but I have already defined a bean of entity ManagerFactory I have edited the question can you have a look please?

Comment: Are you sure that your models package (`com.model.entity`) is in your classpath?

Comment: `try.war\WEB-INF\classes\com\model\entity` this is the hirarchy of the package when I extract my war file